# Spring Security Login Error : HTTP Status 404 - /j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am trying to configure spring security on my application.But once I enter the username and password and submit the form, I get error

`HTTP Status 404 - /j_spring_security_check The requested resource is not available.`

[image]

Following are the my configuration files :

**web.xml**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/taskTracker-app.xml,/WEB-INF/taskTracker-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/taskTracker-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>taskTracker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>taskTracker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**taskTracker-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
 http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="TaskTrackerLoginController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="viewName">
            <value>/taskTracker/sign-in</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TaskTrackerErrorController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="viewName">
            <value>/taskTracker/error</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="WelcomeController" class="com.tracker.web.controllers.WelcomeController">
        <property name="BusinessLogic">
            <ref bean="BusinessLogic" />
        </property>
        <property name="viewName">
            <value>/taskTracker/welcome</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="nonSecurePageMappings"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/taskTracker/sign-in.html">TaskTrackerLoginController</prop>
                <prop key="/taskTracker/error.html">TaskTrackerErrorController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="PageMappings"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>

                <prop key="/taskTracker/welcome.html">WelcomeController</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**taskTracker-security.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="SecurityService" class="com.tracker.web.security.SecurityService">
        <property name="BusinessLogic">
            <ref bean="BusinessLogic" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:http access-denied-page="/taskTracker/tracker/error.html" auto-config="false">
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/taskTracker/sign-in.html">
        </security:session-management>
        <security:form-login login-page="/taskTracker/sign-in.html" default-target-url="/taskTracker/welcome.html"
            always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/taskTracker/sign-in.html?error=1" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/taskTracker/sign-in.html" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/taskTracker/sign-in.html*" filters="none" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/taskTracker/welcome.html*" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="SecurityService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**taskTracker-app.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
 http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.tracker.data.dao.jdbc.UserJdbcDao">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="BusinessLogic" class="com.tracker.business.logic.TrackerBusinessLogicImpl">
        <property name="userLogic">
            <ref bean="userLogic" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userLogic" class="com.tracker.business.logic.user.UserLogic">
        <property name="userDao">
            <ref bean="userDao" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**SecurityService.java**

```
package com.tracker.web.security;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.tracker.business.logic.TrackerBusinessLogic;
import com.tracker.business.model.User;

public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SecurityService.class);
    private TrackerBusinessLogic trackerBusinessLogic;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        String errMsg = "User with username: " + username;

        User user = trackerBusinessLogic.loadUser(username);
        if(user!=null) {
            // user has been loaded
        } else {
            log.error("User with username: " + username + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    public TrackerBusinessLogic getBusinessLogic() {
        return trackerBusinessLogic;
    }

    public void setBusinessLogic(TrackerBusinessLogic trackerBusinessLogic) {
        this.trackerBusinessLogic = trackerBusinessLogic;
    }
}
```

**sign-in.jsp**

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <h1>Task Tracker Login</h1>
    <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="j_username" value="" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="${param.referrer}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Let me in." class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">
    </form>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Please help me with what am I missing here. Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `sign-in.jsp`, you need to change the `URL` to which you are submitting the login request, which you can achieve as below:

```
<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl" />
```

and use this in your form action:

```
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
```

The `login-processing-url` attribute defaults to `/j_spring_security_check`, and specifies the URL that the login form (which should include the `username` and `password`) should be submitted to, using an HTTP post.

Comment: do you have this `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>` added to your jsp?

Comment: Thanks a lot... now on submit, I get http://localhost:8080/TaskTracker/taskTracker/sign-in.html?error=1 which means the action is getting invoked and returns this URL for failed login attempt... but the issue is that I tried to login with the username and password that does exist..so then why is it that the login is failing ?

Comment: Is it because of failed DB connection. But had that been the case, I would have got JDBC exception in the console log but I haven't got any error.

Comment: there might be some problem while loading the `UserDetails` from `trackerBusinessLogic`.

Comment: Wasn't`/j_spring_security_check` exactly what @MithunSasidharan already placed in the jsp by himself ?

Comment: No.. they aren't. In my answer I used 'c:url' to convert the relative URL into the application context's url.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed that error when add ${request.contextPath} before /j_spring_security_check

Answer (score 2):

Not related to this particular problem (but related with "j_spring_security_check 404" issue). Thought it might help anyone trying to solve the same problem with spring 4, even when all the settings are correct.

Since Spring 4, spring has csrf enabled by default, so first check with csrf disabled, if this solves "j_spring_security_check 404" issue.

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

This is just for test, and if it does work, then enable it again, because disabling csrf is not a good idea for web-app these days. So remove that

```
<csrf disabled="true" />
```

line ('coz crsf is enabled by default), and add a csrf token field in your authentication input form as:

```
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
    <input ... />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

OR

```
<form action="${loginUrl}?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" method="post"> .... </form>
```